# Pivot problem the first part works but can't pivot correctly on a particular column to complete it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table just like my simplified temp table with dummy data created below:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
(run int, dateasint int, party varchar(50), total int)

insert into #t (run, dateasint, party, total)
values
(1, 20210101, 'party a', 123),
(1, 20210101, 'party b', 999),
(1, 20210101, 'party c', 234),
(2, 20210102, 'party a', 5457),
(2, 20210102, 'party b', 23536),
(2, 20210102, 'party c', 12563),
(3, 20210103, 'party a', 5744578),
(3, 20210103, 'party b', 3473),
(3, 20210103, 'party c', 34788);
```

I want to pivot this to show the party as the first column, then the dateasint as the following columns containing the totals for each date. Hopefully this makes sense.

This is what I have got so far:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(dateasint) 
                from #t
                group by dateasint
               
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select party, total, dateasint
            from #t
            
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(total)  
            for dateasint in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

This almost gives me the results I'm seeking, per the screenshot below. I just can't work out how to get the party column added on so that it's the first column with 'Party A', 'Party B' and 'Party C' populated in its three rows. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: initial results]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outer select of your query you need to include party:

```
set @query = N'SELECT party, ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select party, total, dateasint
            from #t
            
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(total)  
            for dateasint in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '
```